# Process Builder cannot find the path specified, using AppData folder

Tags: java, process, processbuilder, createprocess

This is probably a simple question, I'm fairly new to Java but in my search I haven't been able to figure out why exactly this code doesn't work.

```
String execLoc = ((System.getenv("APPDATA"))+"\\ARcraft\\exec\\");

ProcessBuilder getCrafting = new ProcessBuilder("Minecraft.exe");
getCrafting.directory(new File(execLoc));
getCrafting.start();
```

When I run this, I get back:

```
Cannot run program "Minecraft.exe" 
(in directory "C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Roaming\ARcraft\exec"): 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've read other posts with similar issues, and tried a variety of solutions but the fixes that they use don't seem to do anything for me. I've confirmed the file is present and that it runs correctly when executed from the directory being fed back by the program when pasted in command prompt.

Comment: If you can guarantee that `C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Roaming\ARcraft\exec\MineCraft.exe` exists, then it has to be a permissions issue. Maybe you should try running your program as Administrator. User folders usually have restricted permissions...

Comment: Have you tried using `ProcessBuilder getCrafting = new ProcessBuilder("C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Roaming\ARcraft\exec\Minecraft.exe");` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer - it'd have to be either ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/andrew/AppData/Roaming/ARcraft/exec/Minecraft.exe");  (preferred) or ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\andrew\\AppData\\Roaming\\ARcraft\\exec\\Minecraft.exe");

Comment: @Andrew: you should use the answer section, not place answers in the question. You should also mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to this in order to just pull the username rather than the appdata path:

```
ProcessBuilder getCrafting = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\" +
    System.getProperty("user.name") + 
    "\\AppData\\Roaming\\ARcraft\\exec\\Minecraft.exe");
getCrafting.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ProcessBuilder` command should be full path to exe file and then it will work:

```
 String execLoc = ((System.getenv("APPDATA"))+"\\ARcraft\\exec\\Minecraft.exe");
 ProcessBuilder getCrafting = new ProcessBuilder(execLoc);
 getCrafting.start();
```